# Swift - How to write complex objects to Firebase realtime database

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, dictionary, firebase-realtime-database

I'm new to the Firebase realtime database and relatively new to Swift in general. I am attempting to build a song request app in which users can create events for guests to request songs from the Spotify API. I'm trying to write an Event object to Firebase, which contains nested objects and arrays of different types. However, when it writes to the database, it only writes the strings and none of the arrays or objects. What is the best way to write all this information to the Firebase Database in a nested structure, so that whenever users add song requests, I can edit the array of requests for the given event in firebase.

Here is my code:

Event.swift

```
struct Event: Codable{

    var code: String
    var name: String
    var host: String
    var description: String
    var hostUserId: String
    var guestIds: [String]
    var requests: [Request]
    var queue: [Request]
    var played: [Request]
    //private var allowExplicit: Bool
    //private var eventLocation

    init(code: String, name: String, host: String, description: String, hostUserId: String){
        self.code = code
        self.name = name
        self.host = host
        self.description = description
        self.hostUserId = hostUserId
        self.guestIds = []
        self.requests = []
        self.queue = []
        self.played = []
    }

    func toAnyObject() -> Any{
        var guestIdsDict: [String:String] = [:]
        for id in guestIds{
            guestIdsDict[id] = id
        }
    
        var requestsDict: [String: Any] = [:]
        for request in requests{
            requestsDict[request.getId()] = request.toAnyObject()
        }
    
        var queueDict: [String: Any] = [:]
        for request in queue{
            queueDict[request.getId()] = request.toAnyObject()
        }
    
        var playedDict: [String: Any] = [:]
        for request in played{
            playedDict[request.getId()] = request.toAnyObject()
        }
    
        return [
            "code": code,
            "name": name,
            "host": host,
            "description": description,
            "hostUserId": hostUserId,
            "guestIds": guestIdsDict,
            "requests": requestsDict,
            "queue":queueDict,
            "played":playedDict
        ]
    }
}
```

Request.swift

```
struct Request: Codable{
    private var name: String
    private var id: String
    private var explicit: Bool
    private var album: Album
    private var artists: [Artist]
    private var likes: Int

    init(name: String, id: String, explicit: Bool, album: Album, artists: [Artist]){
        self.name = name
        self.id = id
        self.explicit = explicit
        self.album = album
        self.artists = artists
        self.likes = 1
    }

    func toAnyObject() -> Any{
        var artistsDict: [String:Any] = [:]
        for artist in artists {
            artistsDict[artist.id] = artist.toAnyObject()
        }
        return [
            "name": name,
            "id": id,
            "explicit": explicit,
            "album": album.toAnyObject(),
            "artists": artistsDict,
            "likes": likes
        ]
    }

    mutating func like(){
        self.likes += 1
    }

    mutating func unlike(){
        self.likes -= 1
        if(self.likes < 0){
            self.likes = 0
        }
    }

    mutating func setLikes(count: Int){
        self.likes = count
    }

    func getLikes() -> Int{
        return self.likes
    }

    func getName() -> String{
        return self.name
    }

    func getId() -> String{
        return self.id
    }

    func getExplicit() -> Bool{
        return self.explicit
    }

    func getAlbum() -> Album {
        return self.album
    }

    func getImages() -> [Image] {
        return self.album.images
    }

    func getArtists() -> [Artist] {
        return self.artists
    }

    func getArtistString() -> String{
        var artistString = ""
        for (i, artist) in self.artists.enumerated(){
            artistString += artist.name
            if(i != self.artists.endIndex-1){
                artistString += ", "
            }
        }
        return artistString
    }
}
```

Album.swift

```
struct Album: Codable{
    let name: String
    let images: [Image]

    func toAnyObject() -> Any{
        var imagesDict: [String: Any] = [:]
        for image in images{
            imagesDict[image.url] = image.toAnyObject()
        }
        return [
            "name": name,
            "images": imagesDict
        ]
    }
}
```

Artist.swift

```
struct Artist: Codable{
    let id: String
    let name: String

    func toAnyObject() -> Any{
        return ["id": id, "name": name]
    }
}
```

Image.swift

```
struct Image: Codable{
    let height: Int
    let url: String
    let width: Int

    func toAnyObject() -> Any{
        return ["height": height, "url": url, "width": width]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you are using Codable, you can create a dic out of it as follows:

Step 1: Add this extension to your code

```
extension Encodable {
  var dictionary: [String: Any]? {
    guard let data = try? JSONEncoder().encode(self) else { return nil }
    return (try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: .allowFragments)).flatMap { $0 as? [String: Any] }
  }
}
```

Step 2: Write below code in your Struct (this you have to do in every struct or you can modify code as per your need).

```
func createDic() -> [String: Any]? {
    guard let dic = self.dictionary else {
        return nil
    }
    
    return dic
}
```

Now with the help of struct obj, call createDic() method and you will get a dictionary.

And you can send this dictionary to the firebase.

**FULL CODE EXAMPLE:**

```
extension Encodable {
      var dictionary: [String: Any]? {
      guard let data = try? JSONEncoder().encode(self) else { return nil }
}

struct LoginModel: Codable {
    let email: String
    let password: String
    
    func createDic() -> [String: Any]? {
        guard let dic = self.dictionary else {
            return nil
        }
        
        return dic
    }
}
```

Please comment if you have any questions.

Happy to help!

Comment: Thank you for your help and quick response! This works exactly as I intended.

Comment: Great!!! Happy Coding. Please don't forget to upvote when you will be able to do so. Thanks

Comment: @MohitKumar can you please take a look at this issue and provide your advice? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63911991/issue-reading-firebase-realtime-database-parent-node-with-children-nodes-in-swif/63912713?noredirect=1#comment113041060_63912713

Comment: @MohitKumar sorry, I do not understand totally.. can you please show by example how to implement your solution!?

Comment: @Learn2Code Example added. Please let me know if this solves your issue.

Comment: If your problem is solved...don’t forget to vote up.

Comment: Genius. I called it like this  func sendEndGameDataToFirebase() {
        let uuid = UUID().uuidString
        let data = dataModel.createDic()
        self.ref.child("\(uuid)").setValue(data)
    }